# Почему не выводятся буквы pyautogui?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

Почему то когда я ввожу например

```
pyautogui.typewrite('Hello world!')
```

у меня выводит только

```
!
```

Кто-нибудь с таким сталкивался?
P.S. при выполнении программы у меня стоит английская раскладка.

Answer (score 0):

Суть в том, что у меня стоял язык ввода по умолчанию русский, я поменял на английский и всё заработало.